# How to obtain foreign field values?

Tags: 7, nodes, entities

I am really new to drupal and struggle to find good tutorials
for the issues I have. One of those issues is as follows:

How do I obtain values from foreign nodes.
Specifically nodes that were created in a feature bundle.

As a concrete example I would like to load all Jobs from the Recruiter
distribution and then extract the field information from them.

After reading through the Book Pro Drupal 7 Development and
many online resource I still struggle to grasp how I am supposed
to do this other than to do direct Database Queries.

Comment: It sounds like you've used the Recruiter distribution and created content but now want to use that content outside of the distribution?

Comment: I want to parse the Job information ( to xml ) to send it somewhere outside of Drupal/Recruiter yes.

Comment: If it's a once-off, try https://www.drupal.org/project/views_data_export The distribution page says it uses 3 content types so I presume you should be able to access everything in views and build an export.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll look into this immediately. Do you also have a hint how one would solve this with native Drupal functions?

Comment: I guess Views has an RSS Feed thing built in.. Could have a look at that. Or a regular Views table. I'm not really sure how I'd go about it without Views.

Comment: I looked into it and sadly this is not what I need, BUT the implementation with views is interesting. I currently try to find how to 'query' a view with all the information that I need, if someone has a pointer for me that would be awesome.

Comment: You could also try https://www.drupal.org/project/views_datasource as it allows creating XML displays of views

Answer (score 0):

There are a few options you have when it comes to exporting data from Drupal 7. A few have been mentioned in this post. Hope this helps!

[How to export/import all nodes of a specific content type?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/41003/how-to-export-import-all-nodes-of-a-specific-content-type)